# Why NestJS mysql query error does not contain all the execution context but stops at process._tickCalback?

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs

**Updated:**
It seems Node.js **v10** up to **14.15.0** had some bugs with the stack trace. My problem resolved after updating to **14.16.1**.
[Check here some of the related issues](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed%20trace%20in%3Atitle)

**A small project that replicates this problem:** https://github.com/babaliaris/nestjs-error-context-problem

[this is the line that the stack trace does not mention](https://github.com/babaliaris/nestjs-error-context-problem/blob/124f7cd4c47afa9522316885552a0ad96075b2dd/src/app.controller.ts#L19)

I have a call execution that goes like this:

```js
1) users.controller.ts calls await insert(table_name, query, data) inside a try-catch block.
2) mysql.service.ts implements the insert() method which calls
3) mysql.query() an npm module that rejects a promise due to a non-existing table name.
```

The stack trace that I get is the following:

```js
[Nest] 31018   - 05/08/2021, 6:55:20 PM   [POST /api/users] Internal Error +20932ms
Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'agro_ajenda_test.t_user' doesn't exist
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/babaliaris/Development/web/nestjs/agro-ajenda-backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/babaliaris/Development/web/nestjs/agro-ajenda-backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:79:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/babaliaris/Development/web/nestjs/agro-ajenda-backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/home/babaliaris/Development/web/nestjs/agro-ajenda-backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/home/babaliaris/Development/web/nestjs/agro-ajenda-backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/home/babaliaris/Development/web/nestjs/agro-ajenda-backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/babaliaris/Development/web/nestjs/agro-ajenda-backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/babaliaris/Development/web/nestjs/agro-ajenda-backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/babaliaris/Development/web/nestjs/agro-ajenda-backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (/home/babaliaris/Development/web/nestjs/agro-ajenda-backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:198:25)
    at connect.then (/home/babaliaris/Development/web/nestjs/agro-ajenda-backend/dist/services/mysql/mysql.service.js:27:22)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

The last context is

```js
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

but it should be something like

```js
at insert() (/home/babaliaris/Development/web/nestjs/agro-ajenda-backend/dist/controllers/users/users.controller.js:27:22)
```

For some reason, it does not tell me where I'm catching the error but the stack stops
in that **process._tickCalback**

Other *mysql.MysqlError* like **ER_BAD_DB_ERROR** contain the call from the **users.controller.js** file but **ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE** does not!

What is going on?

Comment: I just run your code with different output:
 at AppService.insert (/xxx/dist/app.service.js:33:16)
 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
 at async AppController.getHello (xxx/dist/app.controller.js:23:20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This bug exists on node `v10.24.0`, upgrade node to `12+` can solve it.

---

I have different result as I stated in the comment.
So I examine different node versions and find that v10 is not handling the error correctly and return the same error you mentioned.

May I ask if you are using node 10?

If yes, can you try the next LTS `node 12` or the `latest node 16` to see if the problem is gone.

Comment: Yes, my current node version is `v10.24.0`. 
Woh, I updated to the next stable version `v14.16.1` and it works!!!
So it wasn't my bug! It's the first time that this happens to me, usually 100% when I run to problems, the bug is my fault and not the technology that I'm using.

Comment: You can edit your answer to mention this bug in node `v10.24.0`. I accepted your answer!